# Orthogonal circles in Modern Geometry

Tags: geometry, circles

Si una recta trazada por un punto de intersección de dos circunferencias corta nuevamente a las circunferencias en $P$ y $Q$, respectivamente, desmuéstrese que las circunferencias con centros P y Q, cada una ortogonal a la otra, son ortogonales entre sí.

Attempt traslation:

A line drawn through the point of intersection of two circles $C_1$ and $C_2$ intersects the circles again at $P$ and $Q$ respectively. Show that if the circles with centers $P$ and $Q$ are orthogonal to $C_2$ and $C_1$, respectively, they are also orthogonal to each other.

[image]

My progress is at follows:

In the figure, let

- $C_1$ be the blue circumference and $O_1$ its center.
- $C_2$ be the green circumference and $O_2$ its center.

Let $E$ be their meet point. $PQ$ is an aribitrary line through $E$, as in the problem.

Now,

- $D_1$, red circumference, with center in $P$, is orthogonal to $C_2$
  and $C$ is their intersection point
- $D_2$, pink circumference, with center in $Q$, is orthogonal to $C_1$
  and $G$ is their intersection point

Then, $\angle O_{1}GQ = \angle O_{2}CP = 90^{\circ}$

Let $H$ be the intersection point of $D_1$ and $D_2$, I want to show that $\angle PHQ = 90^{\circ}$, wich is the same, $\left(\overline{PQ}\right)^{2} = \left(\overline{PH}\right)^{2} + \left(\overline{HQ}\right)^{2}$

$D_{1}\bot C_{2} $ implies that
$$\left(\overline{O_{2}P}\right)^{2} = \left(\overline{PC}\right)^{2} + \left(\overline{CO_{2}}\right)^{2} = \left(\overline{PH}\right)^{2} + \left(\overline{O_{2}Q}\right)^{2}$$

Analogously,

$D_{2}\bot C_{1} $ implies that
$$\left(\overline{O_{1}Q}\right)^{2} = \left(\overline{QG}\right)^{2} + \left(\overline{GO_{1}}\right)^{2} = \left(\overline{HQ}\right)^{2} + \left(\overline{O_{1}P}\right)^{2}$$

By adding and rearranging

$$\left(\overline{PH}\right)^{2} + \left(\overline{HQ}\right)^{2} =\left(\overline{O_{2}P}\right)^{2} + \left(\overline{O_{1}Q}\right)^{2} - \left(\overline{O_{2}Q}\right)^{2} -\left(\overline{O_{1}P}\right)^{2} $$

How can I continue? It's the right way?

P.S.I apologize for possible misspellings, indeed I don´t speak english

Comment: The originial problem is here, and I  made and attemp of its translation. In the problem and by using my notation thats mean $D_{1}\bot C_{2}$ and $D_{2}\bot C_{1}$

Comment: This should implies that $D_{1}\bot D_{2}$

Comment: The problem is not precisely stated. I think it should be: If a line drawn through the point of intersection of two circles  $C_1$ and $C_2$ intersects the circles at $P$ and $$ respectively, show that the circles with centers $$ and $$, orthogonal to $C_2$ and $C_1$ respectively,  are orthogonal to each other.

Comment: Or: Si una recta que pasa por el punto de intersecci'on de las circunferencias $C_1$ y $C_2$ intersecta a las mismas en $P$ y $Q$, respectivamente, entonces las circunferencias centradas en $P$ y $Q$, ortogonales a $C_2$ y $C_1$ respectivamente, son ortogonales entre s'i.

Comment: @GReyes That's means, the original problem it's in Howard Eves: _Estudio de las geometrías_, 2.7-19. I don't know the edition

Comment: I see.. it might be a translation error. In any case, I am pretty sure, from your drawing, that the correct statement is the one I included above. There are shortcuts in English that do not exist in Spanish and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\C{{\cal C}}$
Let $r_1,r_2,r_P,r_Q$ be the radii of the circles ${\C_1,\C_2,\C_P,\C_Q}$ centered at $O_1,O_2,P,Q$, respectively.

From the orthogonality of $\C_P$ and $\C_2$, and that of $\C_Q$ and $\C_1$ it follows:
$$
PO_2^2=r_P^2+r_2^2,\quad QO_1^2=r_Q^2+r_1^2.\tag1
$$

Now by the [power of a point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point) we have:
$$
\begin{align}
PE\cdot PQ&=PO_2^2-r_2^2=r_P^2\tag{2a}\\
QE\cdot QP&=QO_1^2-r_1^2=r_Q^2\tag{2b}\\
\end{align}
$$
Summing the two equalities one obtains:
$$
PQ^2=r_P^2+r_Q^2,\tag3
$$
which is equivalent to the claim.